# Tips on field recording set up

Tags: field-recording, rode, television

Hey guys, I'm about to go on a Television shoot in the wild and I was wondering if you could give me tips or hints that could help me out with one of the set ups that I will be using

The set up will consist of a Rode NT-2 mic which will be connected to an Azden fmx-22 mixer and from the mixer into a Panasonic HDC-Z10000 camera.

Are there any tips, hints or opinions on this set up which will help me record good sound???

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitor audio from the camera, not the mixer. All too often, people set perfectly usable levels on the mixer and screw it up at the camera. Monitoring from the final device in the chain will help ensure that you get good audio. Make sure you use a reference tone when setting your headphone levels as well.

Comment: How would I go about by setting my headphone levels as the Azden fmx 22 doesn't have a reference tone generator?

Comment: @Airs - most professional cameras have built in tone generators. you can use that to adjust the level of your headphones and give yourself a point of reference for recording levels.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the  Rode NTG-2. If so, be careful with it as it's not as sturdy as the NTG-3. Don't use it in freezing temperatures and generally treat it as something easily breakable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and yes it is the Rode NTG-2 that I am talking about :) If I may ask, why it is a bad idea to use it in freezing temperatures? 

Answer (score 0):

The Panasonic HDC-Z10000 only does 16bit, in post remember this if you have to change everything to 24bit.

With the Rode, use a battery in the shotgun rather than Phantom off the device (if it has it) I find you get a better reading in my experience.

In regards to @Shaun comment definitely read you're levels off the camera, if you have no visual aid just make sure you're not peaking from your mixer and it sounds okay from the camera output.